# Install move-analyzer got "Connection to server got closed"

Tags: aptos

Hi I'm following the instruction in the move-analyzer extension to install it but it emits this error. How can I fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try intellij with Move Language plugin made by Pontem. VS Code has an extension called aptos-move-analyzer, but it's not as feature complete as the intellij plugin.